# A non-graded Gorenstein Artin $k$-algebra such that its associated graded ring is also Gorenstein

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, gorenstein

> I am wondering if there is a non-graded Gorenstein Artin $k$-algebra $R$ such that its associated graded ring, $\mathrm{gr}(R)$, is also Gorenstein.

All the non-graded Gorenstein rings I tried so far have not Gorenstein associated graded rings.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=k[x,y]/(xy^2, x^3-y^2)$. Then $\text{gr}(R)=k[x,y]/(x^4,y^2)$.

$R$ is nongraded Gorenstein and $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ is also Gorenstein.

Answer (score 0):

Let R be a field. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: A field is graded, isn't it?