# How to compute associated graded algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying understand associated graded algebras.

> Let $A=k[x,y]$ and $I=\langle xy^2, x^3-y^2 \rangle$. Let $R=A/I$. In the [webpage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161323/example-needed-r-non-graded-gorenstein-and-grr-is-also-gorenstein-artin-k-alg), it is said that $\mathrm{gr}(R) = A/(x^4, y^2)$.

Let $A=k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and ``$>$'' a monomial order on $A$. For a polynomial $p$, denote by $in_>(p)$ the ideal the term of $p$ with the largest monomial. For an ideal $I$ of $A$, the initial ideal of $I$ is defined as $in_{>}(I) = \langle in_{>}(p) \mid p \in I \rangle$.

I think that $gr(R)$ is isomorphic to $A/in(I)$ as a vector space, where $in(I)$ is the initial ideal of $I$. Is this correct? I obtain that $gr(R)$ is isomorphic to $k[x,y]/(xy^2, x^3, y^4)$ as a vector space. Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to use a different term order, not monomial order. The largest terms are the terms of the least degree. For $x^3-y^2$, it is $y^2$ since it is of the least degree.

Comment: @LJR I don't understand: do you want to compute the associated graded ring as a $k$-vector space or to figure out why the associated graded ring is $A/(x^4,y^2)$?

Comment: Looking at the history of your questions you seem to be puzzled by the isomorphism from that webpage and what you got. But if you count the dimension of both vector spaces can conclude that these are also isomorphic.

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much. I would like to figure out why the associated graded ring is $A/(x^4, y^2)$. How to compute $gr(A/I)$ as a ring? I think we can compute $gr(A/I)$ as a vector space by computing $A/in(I)$. But I don't know how to compute $gr(A/I)$ as a ring.

Comment: @LJRL I don't have a method for computing the associated graded ring. In this particular case I'd simply try to find out the relations satisfied by x and y in the associated graded ring.